How to show that $g_{F}: 2^{\mathbb{N}} \to 2^{\mathbb{N}} $ given by $g_{F}(C) = C \triangle F$ is a homeomorphism, with F a finite subset of natural
First, I want to show that $g_{F}$ is continuous.
Given $U \subseteq 2^{\mathbb{N}}$ an open set, then we get that
$$g_{F}^{-1}(U) = \{C \in 2^{\mathbb{N}}: g_{F}(C) = C \triangle F \in U\}.$$
I'm stuck here and think that my confusion is because I see the elements of the cantor space as functions of ones and zeros instead of a subset of natural numbers.
Also, I thought that since $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$, we can think of the open sets of the cantor space as open sets of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ and in this way the function $g_F$ is a homeomorphism as $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ has the discrete topology. However, I'm not sure about this reasoning.

Which topology does $2^\mathbb N$ have? You suggest it has the discrete topology, but I guess it should have the product topology. Does $Δ$ denote symmetric difference? Please edit your question to clarify these points.

Yes, It's the product topology. I said the discrete because I thought it being homeomorphic to $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$. And yes, $\triangle$ stands for symmetric difference.

I would say that, in general, it is better to think of elements of the Cantor space as functions of 0s and 1s than considering them as subsets of natural numbers for proving topological results.
In particular, since the set $F$ is finite, we can consider it as an infinite sequence $f \in 2^\omega$ starting with $\langle f_0, \dots, f_n \rangle \in 2^n$ (where $n$ is the biggest element in $F$ and $f_i = 1 \iff i \in F$) and continuing with infinite zeros (i.e. $f$ is the characteristic function of $F$).
Therefore we can express the function $g_F:2^\omega \to 2^\omega$ as: $g_F(x) = \langle (x_0 + f_0) \mod 2, \dots, (x_n + f_n) \mod 2, x_{n+1}, x_{n+2},\dots \rangle$.
Now, to check the continuity we can prove that are open the preimages of the clopen sets of the form $N_s = \{ x \mid s \prec x \}$ $\forall s \in 2^{<\omega}$ (where $s \prec x$ means that $s$ is an initial segment of $x$).
For clarity, given $N_s$ I will consider two cases (but they are essentially the same):

$\operatorname{len}(s) \le n$: $g^{-1}_F(N_s) = \bigcup \{ N_z \mid \operatorname{len}(s) = \operatorname{len}(z) \land \bigwedge_{i=0}^{\operatorname{len}(s)}((z_i + f_i) \mod 2 = s_i) \}$
$\operatorname{len}(s) > n$: $g^{-1}_F(N_s) = \bigcup \{ N_z \mid \operatorname{len}(s) = \operatorname{len}(z) \land \bigwedge_{i=0}^{n}((z_i + f_i) \mod 2 = s_i) \land \bigwedge_{i=n+1}^{\operatorname{len}(z)}(z_i = s_i) \}$

In both cases we have the preimages are open, hence $g_F$ is continuous.

There is something that doesn't make sense to me. In the second case, $\len(s)  > n$, if $\len(s) = \len(z)$ then the last condition $i$ ranges from $\len(z)+1$ to $\len(z)$.

@JhanHadderHernandezTunubala Unfortunately you need \operatorname{len} to get $\operatorname{len}$.

@JhanHadderHernandezTunubala You're right! I wrote $\operatorname{len}(s)$ insted of $n$. I edited my answer now it should work.

@NON Is it necessary that $\operatorname{len}(s) = \operatorname{len}(z)$ when you define those open sets?

@JhanHadderHernandezTunubala No it's not necessary. The important thing is that you can express the preimage of each $N_s$ as union of some $N_z$ since they are a basis of the product topology for the Cantor set. For example, in the first case, one can write: $g_F^{-1}(N_s) = { N_r \mid \operatorname{len}(r) \ge \operatorname{len}(s) \land \bigwedge_{i=0}^{\operatorname{len}(s)} ((r_i + f_i) \mod 2 = s_i) }$.

Note that you are dealing with a (compact) topological group ( $(\mathbb{Z}/2)^I$) and the given map is "multiplication by a fixed element of the group" ($F$ finite is not important)

Who is $I$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/2)^I$?

@JhanHadderHernandezTunubala: $I$ is any non-void set. $\mathbb{N}$ works but others do too.
